# Erro ao redefinir alarme com o AlarmManager logo após de cancelar o mesmo

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Eu tenho um alarme definido para despertar numa determinada hora e repetir de 5 em 5 minutos. Mas depois de algumas repetições, eu defino automaticamente o cancelamento do mesmo, isso é, chamo o método para cancelar "`cancelAlarm();`" e em seguida chamo o método `setNewAlarm();`

Mas quando chega no segundo método, retorna-me o seguinte erro:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11525
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Agradecia uma ilustração de algo que eu supostamente não esteja a ver. Obrigado. Abaixo o código:

#### File1.java

```java
File2 f2 = new File2();
File3 f3 = new File3();
if (lunchHour == hr && lunchMinute == minut && secs == 0) {  
    f3.cancelAlarm(context);
    f2.setNewAlarm();
} else {
    if (finishWorkHour == hr && finishWorkMinute == minut && secs == 0) { 
        f3.cancelAlarm(context);
        f2.setNewAlarm();
    }
}
```

#### File2.java

```java
public void setNewAlarm() {

    int afterLunchHour = 17;
    int afterLunchMinute = 58;

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(SentadoAlmoco.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SentadoAlmoco.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    //Set the alarm to start at a specific time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, afterLunchHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, afterLunchMinute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 5, pi);
}
```

Comment: Mostra mais do código. Só as funções chamadas não ajuda muito.

Comment: @LucasNunes .. FYI

Comment: Em que momento está chamando esse código que manipula arquivo e chama o `setNewAlarm`? Cuidado porque o erro é claro, está chamando esse código antes de chamar o `onCreate` da superclasse do seu contexto.

Comment: @Wakim, nesse trecho de código, eu omiti o método onCreate ... Na verdade, eu quero saber, se é possível cancelar o alarm actual setado e logo sem seguida setar um novo alarm?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Recomendo você utilizar de Services para fazer o gerenciamento dos alarmes!

Comment: @FelipeBonezi Blz